# SvelteJs: Deep observe on computed properties

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

As of now we can do the below using computed properties.

```
isTypeRange: ({ field }) => {
        return field && field.type === "Range";
      }
```

Can we do something anything like this?

```
fieldLength: ({field.values.length}) => {
  return field.values.length;
}
```

Following this link https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/11 eventually led me to https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-extras/. But that again explains deep observe.

Update:
P.S.
I know {field.values.length} is invalid javascript, I am just trying to show what I want to achieve. Meaning observing nested properties similar to how ember does

```
fieldLength: Ember.computed('field.values.[]', {
get(){}, set(){}
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no — in Svelte, changes are tracked at the top level (of a component, or of a [store](https://svelte.technology/guide#state-management)), as monitoring nested properties separately would involve a lot more code and internal book-keeping. So `fieldLength` will be recalculated whenever `field` changes (where a 'change' can mean either a new object, or a mutation of the existing one unless you're using the [immutable](https://svelte.technology/guide#immutable) option). Nothing that *depends* on `fieldLength` will be updated unless the length has changed, however.

The longer answer is that `({field.values.length}) => ...` is invalid JavaScript, but there is a valid (if sightly confusing-looking) way to express the same idea:

```js
fieldLength: ({field:{values:{length}}}) => length
```

It's *possible* that future versions of Svelte could track nested properties and only recompute values when they change — if so, it would figure out which nested properties were dependencies by using that destructuring syntax. But regardless of our future intentions that's an approach that will work today, albeit with the occasional unnecessary recomputation.

Comment: Thanks Rich. Yeah I know it is invalid, I was just trying to show what I meant. P.S. If you are the [one of the]creator of svelte, Kudos to you. It's an amazing light weight framework